# how to render only part of html with data using django

Tags: python, django, django-templates, rendering

I am using ajax to sort the data which came from search results.

Now I am wondering whether it is possible to render just some part of html so that i can load this way:

`$('#result').html('&nbsp;').load('/sort/?sortid=' + sortid);`

I am doing this but I am getting the whole html page as response and it is appending the whole html page to the existing page which is terrible.

this is my views.py

```
def sort(request):
  sortid = request.GET.get('sortid')
  ratings = Bewertung.objects.order_by(sortid)
  locations = Location.objects.filter(locations_bewertung__in=ratings)
  return render_to_response('result-page.html',{'locs':locations},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

how can I render only that `<div id="result"> </div>` from my view function? or what am I doing here wrong?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From what I understand you want to treat the same view in a different way if you receive an ajax request.
I would suggest splitting your `result-page.html` into two templates, one that contains only the div that you want, and one that contains everything else and includes the other template (see [django's include tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#include)).

In your view then you can do something like the following:

```
def sort(request):
    sortid = request.GET.get('sortid')
    ratings = Bewertung.objects.order_by(sortid)
    locations = Location.objects.filter(locations_bewertung__in=ratings)
    if request.is_ajax():
        template = 'partial-results.html'
    else:
        template = 'result-page.html'
    return render_to_response(template,   {'locs':locations},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

results-page.html:

```
<html>
   <div> blah blah</div>
   <div id="results">
       {% include "partial-results.html" %}
   </div>
   <div> some more stuff </div>
</html>
```

partial-results.html:

```
{% for location in locs %}
    {{ location }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: That's simple & clever