# Django - show an image when a submit button is clicked

Tags: python, django

[image]

I would like to show an image when a user clicks a submit button.
I want to just change the image, not render the whole page. 
What is the best way to do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16110099/how-to-render-only-part-of-html-with-data-using-django I am following this.

Comment: This is not how StackOverflow works. This site require you to show something that you have tried already. I see no example or any thought given to solving the problem on your own.

Comment: @OptimusCrime I will keep in mind. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have the images loaded to the page AJAX. Use Django template and tags to form the logic for a submission.

```
{% if form submission %}
 {% if lion %}
   {% include '<img>' %} 
 {% elif dog %}
 ........
```

Comment: Can you show me a complete example with codebase? That would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `<iframe>` from html5 to achieve your goal.

[example](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp)